# Selecting/deselecting multiple polygons in leaflet to update plotly chart using R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, plotly, reactive

I'm building an R Shiny app. I want reactive plots (plotly) that highlight one or more counties when they are clicked on the map (leaflet). When a highlighted county is clicked again, I want it to be removed.

Ideally I'd also like the reverse, where clicking on a bar in the plot also highlights it and the respective county on the map, but that is a lower priority.

I have tried to adapt code from multiple related posts (especially [Changing styles when selecting and deselecting multiple polygons with Leaflet/Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104576/changing-styles-when-selecting-and-deselecting-multiple-polygons-with-leaflet-sh) and [R leaflet highlight options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46209309/r-leaflet-highlight-options)), but can't figure it out.

Problems to solve:

1. Proxy adds new polygons but does not remove when clicked a second time
2. I want the proxy to have a green outline so that the original choropleth is still visible, but instead it fills it in all white.
3. I want to apply the same type of proxy update to the plotly bar chart, but I'm waiting to do that until I figure it out with the leaflet.

Here is a simple reprex using a dummy dataset and percent variable like what I will be using.

```
#MAP REPREX

library(sf)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(tidycensus)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)

# GET DATA

NC_counties <- tigris::counties("North Carolina", cb=TRUE, year=2018)%>% st_as_sf()%>% st_transform(crs=4326)

NC_counties <- NC_counties %>% mutate(
  pct_water = AWATER/(ALAND+AWATER)*100)


# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(id="page1",
              tabPanel("Data Tracker",
                     fluidRow(column(6, leafletOutput("my_map", height = 300)),
                                column(6, plotlyOutput("comp_bars", height=300))),
              tabPanel("About the data")))
)


# SERVER
server <- function(input,output, session){
  
  
  # CHOROPLETH MAP OF NC COUNTIES 
  output$my_map = renderLeaflet({
    
    data <- NC_counties
    
    var <- NC_counties$pct_water
    
    bins <- c(0,1,5,10,50,100)
    
    pal <- colorBin(palette = c("#dde4e6","#547980"),
                    domain = var,
                    bins = bins,
                    na.color="#cfcfcf")
    
    labels <- sprintf("%s County", data$NAME)%>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
                    
    leaflet(data,
            options=leafletOptions(minZoom=6, maxZoom=6, zoomControl=FALSE))%>%
      setView(-80, 34.7, 6) %>%
      setMapWidgetStyle(list(background= "white"))%>%
      addPolygons(
        fillColor = ~pal(var),
        fillOpacity = 1,
        color = "white",
        weight = 1,
        layerId=~GEOID,
        label = labels,
        labelOptions = labelOptions(style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
                                    textsize = "12px",
                                    direction = "auto")) %>% 
      addLegend(pal = pal, 
                values = ~var, 
                opacity = 1, 
                title = "Percent water",
                position = "bottomleft")
    
  })

  
  # I WANT A PROXY MAP THAT UPDATES TO HIGHLIGHT ONE OR MORE COUNTIES (THAT GET REMOVED ON THE SECOND CLICK)
  
  clicklist <- reactiveValues(ids=vector())
  
  
  observe({
    
  click <- input$my_map_shape_click
  
  clicklist$ids <- c(clicklist$ids, click$id)
  
  selected <- NC_counties[as.character(NC_counties$GEOID) %in% clicklist$ids, ]

  proxy <- leafletProxy("my_map")
  
  proxy %>% 
    addPolygons(data = selected, 
                layerId = ~GEOID,
                color = "#9DE0AD",
                weight = 3, 
                opacity = 1,
                label = labels,
                labelOptions = labelOptions(style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
                                            textsize = "12px",
                                            direction = "auto"))
  
  })
  

  # TOTAL CLAIMS BY COUNTY LINE CHART
  
  output$comp_bars <- renderPlotly({
    
    NC_counties$NAME <- factor(NC_counties$NAME, levels = unique(NC_counties$NAME)[order(NC_counties$pct_water)])
    
        ylabs <- list(
      title = NULL,
      showticklabels = FALSE
    )
    
    fig <- plot_ly(
      x=NC_counties$pct_water,
      y=NC_counties$NAME,
      name = "Percent water",
      type = "bar",
      orientation = 'h',
      marker = list(color = "#cfcfcf"))
    
    fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis=ylabs)
    
    fig
  
  })
  
  # UPDATE BAR CHART WITH SELECTED POLYGONS 

  observeEvent(input$my_map_shape_click, { 
    
        click <- input$my_map_shape_click
    
    clicklist$ids <- c(clicklist$ids, click$id)
    
    selected <- NC_counties[GEOID %in% clicklist$ids, ]
    
    })  

}

# SHINY APP
shinyApp(ui, server)
#MAP REPREX

library(sf)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(tidycensus)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)

# GET DATA

NC_counties <- tigris::counties("North Carolina", cb=TRUE, year=2018)%>% st_as_sf()%>% st_transform(crs=4326)

NC_counties <- NC_counties %>% mutate(
  pct_water = AWATER/(ALAND+AWATER)*100)


# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(id="page1",
              tabPanel("Data Tracker",
                     fluidRow(column(6, leafletOutput("my_map", height = 300)),
                                column(6, plotlyOutput("comp_bars", height=300))),
              tabPanel("About the data")))
)


# SERVER
server <- function(input,output, session){
  
  
  # CHOROPLETH MAP OF NC COUNTIES 
  output$my_map = renderLeaflet({
    
    data <- NC_counties
    
    var <- NC_counties$pct_water
    
    bins <- c(0,1,5,10,50,100)
    
    pal <- colorBin(palette = c("#dde4e6","#547980"),
                    domain = var,
                    bins = bins,
                    na.color="#cfcfcf")
    
    labels <- sprintf("%s County", data$NAME)%>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
                    
    leaflet(data,
            options=leafletOptions(minZoom=6, maxZoom=6, zoomControl=FALSE))%>%
      setView(-80, 34.7, 6) %>%
      setMapWidgetStyle(list(background= "white"))%>%
      addPolygons(
        fillColor = ~pal(var),
        fillOpacity = 1,
        color = "white",
        weight = 1,
        layerId=~GEOID,
        label = labels,
        labelOptions = labelOptions(style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
                                    textsize = "12px",
                                    direction = "auto")) %>% 
      addLegend(pal = pal, 
                values = ~var, 
                opacity = 1, 
                title = "Percent water",
                position = "bottomleft")
    
  })

  
  # I WANT A PROXY MAP THAT UPDATES TO HIGHLIGHT ONE OR MORE COUNTIES (THAT GET REMOVED ON THE SECOND CLICK)
  
  clicklist <- reactiveValues(ids=vector())
  
  
  observeEvent(input$my_map_shape_click, {
    
  click <- input$my_map_shape_click
  
  proxy <- leafletProxy("my_map")
  
  # gather previous and new clicks in single vector
  clicklist$ids <- c(clicklist$ids, click$id)
  
  # subset data
  selected <- NC_counties[as.character(NC_counties$GEOID) %in% clicklist$ids, ]

  #if the current click ID exists in the clicked polygon (if it has been clicked twice)
  if(click$id %in% selected$GEOID){
    
    #define vector that subsets NAME that matches first click ID
    duplicates <- selected$GEOID[selected$GEOID == click$id]
    
    # remove the current click$id AND its name match from the selected shapefile
    clicklist$ids <- clicklist$ids[!clicklist$ids %in% click$id] 
    clicklist$ids <- clicklist$ids[!clicklist$ids %in% duplicates]
    
    #remove that highlighted polygon from the map
    proxy %>% removeShape(layerId = click$id)
    
  } else {
  
    # map highlighted polygons
  proxy %>% 
    addPolygons(data = selected, 
                layerId = ~GEOID,
                color = "#9DE0AD",
                fillOpacity=0,
                weight = 3, 
                opacity = 1,
                highlight = highlightOptions(weight = 0,
                                             color = NA,
                                             bringToFront = T),
                label = labels,
                labelOptions = labelOptions(style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
                                            textsize = "12px",
                                            direction = "auto"))
  }
  
  })
  
  # TOTAL CLAIMS BY COUNTY LINE CHART
  
  output$comp_bars <- renderPlotly({
    
    NC_counties$NAME <- factor(NC_counties$NAME, levels = unique(NC_counties$NAME)[order(NC_counties$pct_water)])
    
        ylabs <- list(
      title = NULL,
      showticklabels = FALSE
    )
    
    fig <- plot_ly(
      x=NC_counties$pct_water,
      y=NC_counties$NAME,
      name = "Percent water",
      type = "bar",
      orientation = 'h',
      marker = list(color = "#cfcfcf"))
    
    fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis=ylabs)
    
    fig
  
  })
  
  # UPDATE BAR CHART WITH SELECTED POLYGONS 

  # to do with plotlyProxy() after map gets resolved
  

}


# SHINY APP
shinyApp(ui, server)
```